# Method ViewModel.Init receives null as parameters when linker "Link All" enabled in MvvmCross at iOS

Tags: ios, mvvm, xamarin.ios, linker, mvvmcross

I am facing such problem: In **MvvmCross 4.4.0** on **iOS project** when I have changed linker mode from "Link Only SDKs" to "Link All", in the Init method of ViewModel I started to get *null* as a parameter of Init Method. Example below. (All other Init methods have same problem).

On PreviousViewModel:

```
public void RedirectToCountry()
{
    /*_countryId != null */
    ShowViewModel<NextViewModel>(new {countryId = _countryId});
}
```

On NextViewModel:

```
 public void Init(string countryId)
    {
        /* countryId == null */
        _countryId = countryId;
    }
```

So,  now I am looking what Method/Class/File/Namespace/Assembly do I need to save from Linker. **Which component should I include?**

P.S.: If someone now khow to save Prepare method from new versions of MvvmCross please answer too.

P.P.S.: I have researched that MvvmCross uses JsonSerializer for transferring data between ViewModels, tried to include assembly with serializer files (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels) but it did not helped.

Comment: This is very weird, because `cityId` is an `int` so it cannot ever be `null`. Are you sure that is what is happening?

Comment: @MartinZikmund, sorry, it was example from my head. Actually there are nullable types. String for example. I have updated question.

Comment: I see :-) ... It is a very interesting problem, I am surprised no one has encountered this yet

Comment: @OlegKosuakiv did you see my answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, including my iOS project helped to pass data between ViewModels.

For example:
--linkskip=GuestGuide.iOS

Also I did not included all MvvmCross assemblies excluding MvvmCross.Binding.

However it all is not understandable by me at all.

Answer (score 1):

These are the assemblies I normally avoid from linking on iOS:

> --linkskip=MvvmCross.Binding --linkskip=MvvmCross.Binding.iOS --linkskip=MvvmCross.Localization --linkskip=MvvmCross.Platform --linkskip=MvvmCross.Platform.iOS --linkskip=Newtonsoft.Json

You shouldn't have any MvvmCross issues when linking all assemblies after that.

Comment: Actually it did not help.

Comment: Looking at your own answer looks like it did help detect it was a linker issue... No problem though, happy coding!